# Using AVAssetWriter to create MPEG-2 TS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm currently using `AVAssetWriter` to take a video saved on disk and transcode it to lower bitrates. This works fine. Ultimately, I would like to have the iPhone create the necessary TS and M3U8 files to then send to a server. I've looked everywhere for examples of how to do this but I have had no luck. My understanding is that MPEG-2 TS only differs in the header structure, but I'm weary of messing with the file directly.

Any thoughts around how to approach this?